# Magento 2: how to add route rewrite URL with install/update of module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Need to add URL rewrite to `Admin -> Marketing -> Url Rewrites` not via Admin but using install/update scripts of my module that it could be done automatically.
How it could be realized?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it in current way: added Vendor/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php and UpgradeData.php. This files contains following code.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Recipe\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $urlRewrite;

    public static $fields = [
        'url_rewrite_id',
        'entity_type',
        'entity_id',
        'request_path',
        'target_path',
        'redirect_type',
        'store_id',
        'description',
        'is_autogenerated',
        'metadata'
    ];
    public static $table = 'url_rewrite';

    public function __construct(
        UrlRewrite $urlRewrite
    ){
        $this->urlRewrite = $urlRewrite;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        self::insertData($setup, $context);
    }

    public function insertData(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        if (!$this->urlRewrite->getCollection()->getItemByColumnValue('request_path', 'oppskrifter')) {
            $fields  = self::$fields;
            $table   = self::$table;
            $columns = [];
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $columns[] = $field;
            }

            $items = [[[null, 'custom', 0, 'oppskrifter', 'recipe/index/index', 0, 1, null, 0, null]]];
            $i     = 0;
            foreach ($items as $data) {
                $setup->getConnection()->insertArray($setup->getTable($table), $columns, $data);
                $i++;
                echo 'Iteration: ' . $i . ', ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone knows better and easier way, so, please, share it.